# Распарсить json и получить результат

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

Здравствуйте, 
делаю get запрос

```
    string k = "helo thera";
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text="+k+"&callback=fix_spell", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

получаю json с нужной мне заменой,

```
fix_spell([{"code":1,"pos":0,"row":0,"col":0,"len":4,"word":"helo","s":["hello"]},{"code":1,"pos":5,"row":0,"col":5,"len":6,"word":"thera\u0435","s":["there"]}])
```

Как мне теперь поменять в переменной k:

helo на hello

thera на there?

Comment: А вы справку по API читали? Что там говорится?

Comment: @VladD читал, но с json никогда не работал, по этому хз как сделать. Вот справка: https://tech.yandex.ru/speller/doc/dg/reference/checkText-docpage/

Comment: А зачем вам callback, если вы собираетесь разбирать JSON?

Comment: @VladD видел на сайте http://saippuakauppias.github.io/autocorrector/ , где это уже реализовано при нажатии на клавишу в запросе была эта функция

Comment: @VladD суть в том что я хочу чтобы он отправило запрос и автоматом поменяло слова

Comment: Ну вы когда копируете код, должны понимать, что конкретно вы делаете. Иначе толку не выйдет.

Comment: @VladD я не понимаю как просто поменять слова которые оно типа там заменило...

Comment: Вы не понимаете, как в строке заменить часть по индексу? о_О

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, для начала, вам нужно установить через nuget JSON.NET. (Имя пакета `Newtonsoft.Json`, устанавливать [так](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui).)

Затем, вам нужно определить класс, в который будет происходить десериализация. Исходя из описания API, вам приходит список таких классов:

```
class Error
{
    public int code, pos, row, col, len;
    public string word;
    public List<string> s;
}
```

Для разбора при помощи JSON.NET используйте

```
var errorList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Error>>(responseString);
```

Затем, имея список, вы можете пройти его с конца (понятно, почему?), и заменять подстроки.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(k);
foreach (var err in list.OrderByDescending(err => err.pos))
{
    sb.Remove(err.pos, err.len);
    sb.Insert(err.pos, err.s.First());
}
k = sb.ToString();
```

---

Да, вы отправляете строку неправильно, потому что вам пришёл результат не со строкой `"thera"`, а со строкой `"theraе"` (последняя Е русская). Выясняйте сами, откуда она появилась.

Comment: Круто, немного пошаманил под себя и вышло, спасибо!

Comment: @СерегаГасюк: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло.

Comment: Может, какой каноничный ответ написать про парсинг json? А то такой вопрос задается уже не в первый раз, я примерно то же самое уже [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/179763)

Comment: @tym32167: Кстати да, хорошая идея, а то вопросы приходят регулярно.