# Как преобразовать json в класс

Tags: c#, json

Есть класс

```
namespace xmltv
{
    public class Event
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string eid { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string finish { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Я хочу входящий json преобразовать в класс

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("axi.json");
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 };
var rez = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Как я понимаю ошибка в параметре десериализации.
Я пробовал

```
List<RootObject>
List<Result>
```

Никак не пойму какой тип данных прописать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я же уже скидывал вам [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/736927#736927), обратите внимание не последнюю строчку там `var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`

Comment: `jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);`

Comment: @tym32167 выдает ошибку. См. на скрине

Comment: У меня вот эта конструкция прекрасно работает с вашим Json `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str)`

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин выдает ошибку

Comment: У меня и `var rez = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(str)` сработал нормально. Покажите полностью ваш Json

Comment: @tym32167  http://disk.karelia.pro/gnrThIr

Comment: Меня туда файрвол не пустит. Если сюда вставить не получается, то смотрите на ваш json и ищите где то в нем ошибку

Comment: @tym32167 https://pastebin.com/27NWAkcf

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70271/discussion-between-radzhab-and-tym32167).

Comment: @tym32167 интересно. С маленьким файлом работает все

Comment: с помощью json.net все получилось

Comment: @Radzhab Птз? :)

Comment: @Radzhab Чат и пастебин у меня тоже недоступны с работы, но я разд, что вы решили проблему :)

Comment: @teran ПТЗ? Петербургский троллейбусный завод?

Comment: @tym32167 Петрозаводск :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В VisualStudio есть встроенный инструмент - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если им воспользоваться, схема преобразуется вот так:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Event[] events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string eid { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int finish { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

Не поможет ли Вам встроенный инструмент?