# Как описать свойства в модели C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! Подскажите, как должны выглядеть свойства модели, если есть следующее представлением клиента (JSON только как пример):

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "Name": "Petr Petrovich",
    "Addresses": [
      {
        "Type": "VISITING",
        "Street": {
          "Street1": "Street 12-12",
          "Street2": "(P.O. Box 190)"
        },
        "PostalCode": "100000",
        "Town": "Bobruisk"
      }
    ],
    "Phone": [
      {
        "Type": "WORK",
        "Value": "+7555 555 555"
      },
      {
        "Type": "MOBILE",
        "Value": "+3 999"
      }
    ],
    "Email": [
      {
        "Type": "WORK",
        "Value": "admin@bobruisk.com"
      }
    ],
    "Notes": "Cool customer."
  }
}
```

Я это описал следующим способом:

```
namespace CustomerApplication.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Адрес 1")]
        public string Street1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Адрес 2")]
        public string Street2 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Почтовый индекс")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Город")]
        public string Town { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Рабочий телефон")]
        public int WorkPhone { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Мобильный телефон")]
        public int MobilePhone { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Заметка")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Активность аккаунта")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Меня смущают некие "type", как их отобразить и нужны ли они вообще? Планируется обычная учётка клиентов (добавление, поиск, редактирование, удаление, сортировка).

Comment: Если вам надо по Json собрать модель, то поглядите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/736927#736927)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все несколько веселее выглядит на самом деле - там сложный объект содержащий в себе другие объекты (аннотации сами проставьте):

```
  public class Street
    {
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Street Street { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public IList<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
        public IList<Email> Email { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Генерировал [тут](https://jsonutils.com/)

Comment: а не подскажете, как добавить такую фитчу: сколько раз профиль клиента изменялся и когда?

Comment: А сервер который json выдает тоже вы пишите или сторонний? Во втором случае боюсь что никак.

Comment: нет, это простое mvc приложение с локальной БД, json вообще для примера был дан, чтобы понять какие данные о клиенте необходимо запоминать.

Comment: Ну так заведите поле, и манипулируйте им .

Comment: так а как это описать в свойстве? public class ProfileUpdate
    {
        public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    } и как подсчитать кол-во то?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос - там сформулируйте конкретно чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Сергей, чтобы не плодить вопросы, вы не подскажете как добавить начальные данные в такую модель? var customer = new Customer
                               {
                                   Name = "John White",
                                   Notes = "Best client",
                                   Active = true,
                                   Email = new List<Email>() { "WORK", "admin@bobruisk.com" }),
                                   Addresses = new List<Addresses>(),
                                   Phone = new List<Phone>()
                               };

Comment: Ну напишите в конструкторе все, передавайте данными параметрами к конструктору.

Comment: написал, все ок. Теперь другой момент, пытаюсь создать контроллер CRUD на модель Customer и мне выдает ошибку "has no key defined" в phone, email, adresses. Указываю в каждом классе [Key][Column(Order=1)], но не работает, подозреваю, что я неверно указываю ключи. Подскажете как должно выглядеть?

Comment: Создавай отдельный вопрос. Запарил уже)