# Получение массива из json. c# Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Получаю с сайта json который содержит кучу массивов и свойств по типу =>

```html
{
  "Status":true
  "Data":{...}
  "INFO":["info1", "info2", "info3"]
}
```

Меня интересует массив INFO, который может содержать от 1 до 5 строк.
Как мне его получить отдельно,игнорирую остальные данные, такие как status и data?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: в данном случае интересно как это сделать с помощью JsonUtility, ибо тут Unity

Comment: указывайте это, пожалуйста, в вопросе, так как, насколько я понимаю, json.net тоже можно пользовать в unity.

Comment: и, кстати, вот это `"INFO":{info1, info2, info3}` - не массив. Это объект с полями info1, info2, info3, значение которых не установлено. Я не уверен, что это вообще валидный json

Comment: в моем случае, в документации написано что это "Массив символьных кодов".

Comment: прошу прощения, ошибся.  Возращает
"INFO":["info1", "INFO2"]

Comment: в чём проблема сериализовать и работать только с нужными полями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cам разобрался.

создаем класс

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string[] INFO;
}
```

Далее делаем

```
ClassName info = JsonUtility.FromJson<ClassName>(myjson);
```

Если кратко, то я просто не знал того, что достаточно того что бы совпадали имена переменных.