# Как распарсить json c#?

Tags: c#, json

мне нужно каким то образом вытянуть нужные данные из json. Я искал очень много ответов но не нашел не один подходящий мне вариант. Использую библиотеку Newtonsoft с Xnet. Извлечь мне нужно uid из такого запроса [ССЫЛКА](https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?&count=1000&access_token=ef9b8c9ada2d543e75113d4af24a17cb86ff2f8e0dab034064f58aaf1bc79f6bcd6d12867214fd369b9fa). 
До этого извлекал токен и все было ок. 
Вот сам код:

```
var log1 = new HttpRequest();
string responsive = log1.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?count=1000&access_token=" + token).ToString();
dynamic root = JObject.Parse(responsive);`
string id = root.uid;
richTextBox1.Text = id;
```

Запрос 
{"response":[118118,{"uid":228022710,"first_name":"Даян","last_name":"Киндяшев"},{"uid":255121183,"first_name":"Света","last_name":"Сашина"},{"uid":144849987,"first_name":"Ксения","last_name":"Галиева"},{"uid":219443008,"first_name":"Денис","last_name":"Михалев"},{"uid":15105460,"first_name":"Екатерина","last_name":"Сидорова"},

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Там не один uid, их целая куча же

Comment: Мне нужно все, в дальнейшем их будет меньше

Comment: Вставьте сюда: https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp получите готовый код

Comment: на so много вопросов посвященных этой теме, посмотрите их вначале http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D++json

Comment: Опубликуйте 1. Часть JSON в текстовом виде. Токена у нас нету что б получить JSON. 2. намеченую структуру, куда вы хотите этот JSON конвертировать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить json в ассоциативный массив / C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-c)