# Парсинг json в C# с помощью newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

Есть json вида:

```
{"hashrate": {"total": [31.97,32.16,32.23]}}
```

Необходимо получить из массива total первое значение "31.97".

Делаю так:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using J = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute;
using R = Newtonsoft.Json.Required;
using N = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling;

...

foreach (var totalh in rootObject.Hashrate.Total){


            label1.Text = "\n\nTotal now hasrate\n" + totalh;

        }

...

public partial class RootObject
{
    [J("hashrate")] public Hashrate Hashrate { get; set; }
}

public partial class Hashrate
{
    [J("total")] public decimal[] Total { get; set; }
}
}
```

В итоге получаю третье значение "32.23"

Как с этим бороться? Желательно с примерами. Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: "Как с этим бороться?" - отладкой, пошагово выполняя программу, ставить брейкпоинты, смотреть какие данные получаются в нужных объектах.

Comment: Честно говоря думал, что проблема в newtonsoft. Оказалось сам тупил по черному. Спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Это массив, следовательно необходимо указать индекс

Первое значение

```
rootObject.Hashrate.Total[0]
```

Второе

```
rootObject.Hashrate.Total[1]
```

Третье

```
rootObject.Hashrate.Total[2]
```

Пример в моем случае

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using J = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute;
using R = Newtonsoft.Json.Required;
using N = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling;

...




        label1.Text = rootObject.Hashrate.Total[0];



...

  public partial class RootObject
  {
    [J("hashrate")] public Hashrate Hashrate { get; set; }
  }

  public partial class Hashrate
  {
    [J("total")] public decimal[] Total { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Избавился от конструкции foreach