# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь победить ошибку уже 4 день., уже весь интернет облазил, пересмотрел много решений, но так и не приблизился к решению проблемы :(

Сам код

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace binance_0._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //заходим на биржу
            String url = "сайт";
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)httpWebResponse).StatusDescription);

            //перевод в джонсон
            string response;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //выцепляем из динамического джонсна пары и их назхвания
            int pr_btc = 0;
            int pr_usd = 0;
            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            JObject jObject = (JObject)stuff["symbol"];
            List<string> pair_btc = new List<string>(); // массив коинов с BTC
            List<string> pair_usd = new List<string>(); // с пары usdt

            //выцепляем из динамического джонсoна пары и их назхвания
            foreach (var data in jObject)
            {

                //формируем массив пар с btc
                if ((data.Key.Contains("BTC")))
                {

                    pair_btc.Add(data.Key);
                    pr_btc++;

                }

                //формируем массив пар с usdt
                if ((data.Key.Contains("USDT")))
                {

                    pair_usd.Add(data.Key);
                    pr_usd++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(jObject);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка происходит в строке

```
foreach (var data in jObject)
```

Ругается на переменную jObject

Подскажите пожалуйста в решение проблемы.

Comment: из кода оставьте только то как получаете  jObject, ваш `foreach (var data in jObject)` и текст ошиьки добавьте, что вам там пишет отладчик!

Comment: отчего бы не попробовать просто [спарсить json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/736927#736927), если вы знаете, как он выглядит

Answer (score 1):

```
JObject jObject = (JObject)stuff["symbol"];
```

Вы здесь делаете явное приведение к типу `JObject`, если приведение не удалось, будет вызвано исключение.

Лучше воспользоваться оператором приведения `as`:

```
var jObject = stuff["symbol"] as JObject;
```

И проверять этот объект на `null`:

```
if (jObject){
    return; //Выход из метода или обработка ошибки
}
```

---

[Примечание:](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as#remarks)

Оператор as аналогичен операции приведения. Однако, если преобразование невозможно, as возвращает null, а не вызывает исключение.

Comment: Если приведение не удалось, в JObject будет null. InvalidCast же будет, а не null.

Comment: @yolosora Да, согласен. Жаль автор не привел текст ошибки, очень странно что компилятор указал на строку с `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробности ошибки

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Сообщение =
>   Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.   Источник =
>   binance   Трассировка стека:    в binance_0._1.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) в C:\Users\Kapusta\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\binance\binance\Program.cs:строка 41