# Как распарсить трехмерный массив json в сущность c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Вот такой ответ приходит с сервера:

```
{
    "data": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1, 
                "name": "Bitcoin", 
                "symbol": "BTC", 
                "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
                "rank": 1, 
                "circulating_supply": 17307362.0, 
                "total_supply": 17307362.0, 
                "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
                "quotes": {
                    "USD": {
                        "price": 6612.10217774, 
                        "volume_24h": 3345977275.98095, 
                        "market_cap": 114438045971.0, 
                        "percent_change_1h": -0.02, 
                        "percent_change_24h": 0.54, 
                        "percent_change_7d": 1.04
                    }
                }, 
                "last_updated": 1538812947
            }
    }
}
```

С помощью библиотеки `json.net` десереализовывал двухмерный массив.Не могу понять как трехмерный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Генерируем классы

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<int, Data> data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string website_slug { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public double circulating_supply { get; set; }
    public double total_supply { get; set; }
    public double max_supply { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Quotes> quotes { get; set; }
    public int last_updated { get; set; }
}

public class Quotes
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double market_cap { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_7d { get; set; }
}
```

парсим

```
string json = @"{
""data"": {
        ""1"": {
            ""id"": 1, 
            ""name"": ""Bitcoin"", 
            ""symbol"": ""BTC"", 
            ""website_slug"": ""bitcoin"", 
            ""rank"": 1, 
            ""circulating_supply"": 17307362.0, 
            ""total_supply"": 17307362.0, 
            ""max_supply"": 21000000.0, 
            ""quotes"": {
                ""USD"": {
                    ""price"": 6612.10217774, 
                    ""volume_24h"": 3345977275.98095, 
                    ""market_cap"": 114438045971.0, 
                    ""percent_change_1h"": -0.02, 
                    ""percent_change_24h"": 0.54, 
                    ""percent_change_7d"": 1.04
                }
            }, 
            ""last_updated"": 1538812947
        }
}
}";
var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Готово.

Подробнее, как это делать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/736927#736927)
При этом не забываем, что в случае ассоциативных массивов надо будет ручками типы поправить на словари.