# Как правильно вытащить значение из JObject

Tags: c#, json

Получаю строку json с ошибкой от сервера ...api

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "FaceNotFound",
    "message": "Face is not found."
  }
}
```

Мне нужно вытащить под значение строки `error` - `FaceNotFound` из "code"
Я пробовал такой способ

```
var cod = verify["code"].Value<string>();
```

Но это не работает

Comment: Ну так а что за объект и как пытаешься вытащить значение?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: Это JObject это json, я знаю как вытаскивать прямые значения `FaicIdbool = verify["isIdentical"].Value<bool>();`, но у меня не получается вытащить под строку `FaceNotFound` из `error`, ответ выше не совсем то что мне нужно, там представлена десериализация всего json , а мне нужно получить одно значение

Comment: Представьте, что JSON это папка с некими файлами/папками внутри. Как вы напишете путь до файла `test.txt`, который находится в папке `logs` на диске `C`? А легко: `С:\logs\test.txt`. Так в JSON все точно также, только надо не забывать и про тип данных (массив например). То есть у вас идет сначала объект `error`, он содержит в себе `code` и `message`. Так и пишите `verify["error"]["code"]`. Но я бы вам не советовал использовать JObject, ибо с ним вы легко можете упустить что либо (особенно, если сменится значение на сервере). Так что советую все же создать структуру из классов и работать с ней!

Comment: Вообще, показанный json принципиально невалиден: подряд две фигурные скобки не разрешены. Покажите _реальный_ json.

Comment: `{"error":{"code":"FaceNotFound","message":"Face is not found."}}` вторые скобки это ошибка при копировании

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вышще указал  EvgeniyZ

```
var cod = verify["error"]["code"].Value<string>();
```