# Как десериализовать json в объекты в C#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Имеется строка в вида:

`{"test":true,"list":[{"a":"aa","b":"bb"},{"a":"aa1","b":"bb1"},{"a":"aa2","b":"bb2"},{"a":"aa3","b":"bb3"}]}`

Как мне ее Deserialize в объекты? Известно, что test - string значение, list - коллекция объектов. Данный обобьет доступен для проекта. Но не могу получить сначала коллекцию объектов, потом string значение.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. **Приведите пример кода, который вы написали**.

Comment: @tym32167 это не ассоциативный массив в общем-то, это ещё более просто.

Comment: @AK ну, тогда дубликат вот [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/179763)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте newtonsoft json

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

Comment: Всё это конечно неплохо и в правильном направлении - но вообще-то не показано самое главное: классы для десериализации (у вас  - Account), да и показать лучше на тех же входных данных, что и у автора.

Answer (score 1):

> Но не могу получить сначала коллекцию объектов, потом string значение.

Вот классы для десериализации:

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("test")]
    public bool Test { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public List[] List { get; set; }
}

public partial class List
{
    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("b")]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

А вот сама десериализация:

```
var source = "{\"test\":true,\"list\":[{\"a\":\"aa\",\"b\":\"bb\"},{\"a\":\"aa1\",\"b\":\"bb1\"},{\"a\":\"aa2\",\"b\":\"bb" +
"2\"},{\"a\":\"aa3\",\"b\":\"bb3\"}]}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(source);
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]