# Превратить array на c# в object json

Tags: c#, json

Есть такой json object:

```
     \"estimated_value\": {
    \"amount\": 123.3,
    \"currency\": \"EUR\"
  },
```

Если сделать так:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> amount = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        amount.Add("amount", price);
        Dictionary<string, string> currency = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        currency.Add("currency", letter.Currency);
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        list.Add(amount);
        list.Add(currency);

        dict.Add("estimated_value", list);
string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

То получится массив с квадратными скобками, а мне это не нужно. Нужно

string => 2 object

Но без массива

Comment: Напишите по желаемому json класс и сериализуйте его

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: все шаги как сгенерировать классы по JSON расписаны [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/179763)

Comment: А без класса тут не обойтись?

Comment: ну вы можете хоть string.format использовать (например, `$("{myjsonvalue:{value}}"`), но класс - самый верный вариант, если вы не хотите потом свой код переделывать на класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за бред вы понаписали?

В заголовке: "Превратить **array** на c# в object json".
В сообщении: "То получится **массив** с квадратными скобками, а мне это не нужно".

Из массива в C# естественно получается массив в json. Если вам не нужен массив, то **не создавайте** его. Элементарно, Ватсон!
На заметку: `List<T>` - считай, тот же массив.

---

Вам бы для начала выучить, что такое JSON.
Тот огрызок данных, что вы поместили в начале, не является json - он не валидный.

Но вообще, там просматривается следующая структура: объект, имеющий свойство `estimated_value`, которое само является объектом с двумя свойствами: `amount`, `currency`.
Заметьте: объекты и свойства! Никаких массивов.

Ну и создавайте объекты со свойствами. Можно анонимные объекты.

```
decimal price = 123.3M;
string letterCurrency = "EUR";

var obj = new
{
    estimated_value = new
    {
        amount = price,
        currency = letterCurrency
    }
};


string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
Console.WriteLine(postData);
```

---

И ещё напутствие: вы пишете на C# - языке со статической типизацией (хотя и динамическая в нём присутствует). В нём принято явно описывать используемые структуры данных. Поэтому создайте неоходимый класс (или классы). Кода для их описания нужно совсем немного. Всяко меньше, чем вы понаписали с `Dictionary`. А далее IDE будет вам выдавать удобные подсказки при использовании этих классов.