# получить ответ на get в JSON

Tags: php, c#, json, get

выполняю запрос через программу git-bash.exe
curl -k -H "X-Authorization:мой_токен" [https://api.evotor.ru/api/v1/inventories/stores/код_магазина/products](https://api.evotor.ru/api/v1/inventories/stores/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/products)
в ответ получаю всё без разделения на строки

```
[{"uuid":"caa34b03-1498-430c-9b13-1765ebc2163d","group":true,"hasVariants":null,"type":null,"name":"Канцтовары","code":"","barCodes":null,"price":null,"costPrice":null,"quantity":0,"measureName":null,"tax":null,"allowToSell":null,"description":null,"articleNumber":null,"parentUuid":null,"alcoCodes":null,"alcoholByVolume":null,"alcoholProductKindCode":null,"tareVolume":null},{"uuid":"e105dd79-ef55-44ba-af78-497d3e8592e5","group":true,"hasVariants":null,"type":null,"name":"Услуги","code":"","barCodes":null,"price":null,"costPrice":null,"quantity":0,"measureName":null,"tax":null,"allowToSell":null,"description":null,"articleNumber":null,"parentUuid":null,"alcoCodes":null,"alcoholByVolume":null,"alcoholProductKindCode":null,"tareVolume":null}]
```

а необходимо получить в формате:

```
[{
  "uuid": "caa34b03-1498-430c-9b13-1765ebc2163d",
  "group": true,
  "hasVariants": null,
  "type": null,
  "name": "Канцтовары",
  "code": "",
  "barCodes": null,
  "price": null,
  "costPrice": null,
  "quantity": 0,
  "measureName": null,
  "tax": null,
  "allowToSell": null,
  "description": null,
  "articleNumber": null,
  "parentUuid": null,
  "alcoCodes": null,
  "alcoholByVolume": null,
  "alcoholProductKindCode": null,
  "tareVolume": null
 }, {
  "uuid": "e105dd79-ef55-44ba-af78-497d3e8592e5",
  "group": true,
  "hasVariants": null,
  "type": null,
  "name": "Услуги",
  "code": "",
  "barCodes": null,
  "price": null,
  "costPrice": null,
  "quantity": 0,
  "measureName": null,
  "tax": null,
  "allowToSell": null,
  "description": null,
  "articleNumber": null,
  "parentUuid": null,
  "alcoCodes": null,
  "alcoholByVolume": null,
  "alcoholProductKindCode": null,
  "tareVolume": null
 }, {
  "uuid": "851d4955-4026-4a46-a770-e2946d22baa6",
  "group": false,
  "hasVariants": null,
  "type": "NORMAL",
  "name": "Тетрадь 48л кл. БиДжи выбор.лак ассорти",
  "code": "",
  "barCodes": ["2469032621510;\n4690326171001;\n4690326171155;\n4690326173654;\n4690326184469;\n4690326187484;\n4690326197360;\n4690326204037;\n4690326214876;\n4690326215101"],
  "price": 4690326208578,
  "costPrice": 27.5,
  "quantity": 5,
  "measureName": "шт",
  "tax": "NO_VAT",
  "allowToSell": false,
  "description": "тетради",
  "articleNumber": "",
  "parentUuid": "caa34b03-1498-430c-9b13-1765ebc2163d",
  "alcoCodes": [],
  "alcoholByVolume": null,
  "alcoholProductKindCode": null,
  "tareVolume": null
 }, {
  "uuid": "002d84bc-f7be-4287-ac36-eadc768c60b5",
  "group": false,
  "hasVariants": null,
  "type": "NORMAL",
  "name": "Русский Стиль Вышивка крестиком с пяльцами.Розочка",
  "code": "",
  "barCodes": ["4602933048058"],
  "price": 280.0,
  "costPrice": 178.87,
  "quantity": 1.0,
  "measureName": "шт",
  "tax": "NO_VAT",
  "allowToSell": true,
  "description": "",
  "articleNumber": "",
  "parentUuid": "caa34b03-1498-430c-9b13-1765ebc2163d",
  "alcoCodes": [],
  "alcoholByVolume": null,
  "alcoholProductKindCode": null,
  "tareVolume": null
 }
```

как выполнить данный запрос через hph или c# (в особенности как правильно указать мой токен), чтобы получить в ответ информацию разделённую на строки?
писал в поддержку на мой вопрос ответили "В Вашем примере ответ представлен в формате текста, разделённого запятой. В формате json будет выглядеть так(из примера взял первую пятерку товаров)", то есть api поддерживает json.

Comment: Что значит `без разделения на строки`? Это JSON, какое вам в нем надо разделение?

Comment: я получаю без переходов на следующую строку, возможно это из за того что я делаю это просто через консоль. Сам переход на следующую строку мне необходим для распознания данного ответа, чтобы можно было точно определить что строка закончилась. пример: ("name": "Услуги",) я могу обозначить конец как ",", но если будет  пример: ("name": "Услуги, ещё что то,",",) то моя программа сломается

Comment: Если вам нужнно распарсить JSON, то используйте для этого [правильные инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/179763). Не пытайтесь его разобрать самостоятельно, только потратите время и все равно будете использовать готовые решения.

Comment: public class Rootobject
{
public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}
public class Class1
 {
public string uuid { get; set; }
public bool group { get; set; }
public bool? hasVariants { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
...
я получил это, но как работать с этим дальше? мне необходимо получить значение 5 полей из всего и сформировать запросы на добавления данных в sql, данные хранятся в файле, подскажите как правильно вызвать функцию и получить 5 строк (uuid, name, ...)

Comment: Я же вам дал ссылку, там все расписано.

Comment: сделал всё по инструкции, получил ошибку Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0."
могу дать ссылку на файл txt, с которым работаю, а так же как можно выполнить "curl -k -H "X-Authorization:мой_токен" https://api.evotor.ru/api/v1/inventories/stores/код_магазина/products" в c# для получения JSON, пытался выполнять как https://api.evotor.ru/api/v1/inventories/stores/код_магазина/products?X-Authorization=мой_токен на что получал ответ ошибка авторизации

Comment: Актуализируйте вопрос, используйте редактирование, добавьте примеры кода.