# Как обращаться к массиву JSON без названия

Tags: c#, json

Имеется массив в файле JSON

```
[
{
"info1":1,
"info2":2,
"info3":3,
},
{
"info1":,
"info2":,
"info3":,
}
]
```

Массив без названия, как я могу к нему обращаться в модели?

```
public class InfoItems
    {
        [JsonProperty("????")]
        public Info[] InfoItem { get; set; }
    }
public class Info
    {
        [JsonProperty("Info1")]
        public int inf1 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Info2")]
        public string inf2 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Info3")]
        public string inf3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Где вы тут увидели массив без названия? Я например вижу корневой объект, который является массивом объектов. Так может все же`.Deserealize<Person[]>` (массив можно заменить для удобства на `List<>`)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да так и сделано, но главная проблема состоит в том, что я не могу обратится напрямую к свойству через LINQ
https://imgur.com/a/pgZE7WM

Comment: Все вы можете, просто пишете не так, вы обращаетесь к `Persons`, естественно там не будет свойств нужных вам, ибо это коллекция. Что вам надо? Достать один объект? Пожалуйста - `var result = Persons.FirstOrDerault(x=>x.inf1 == 5);` Или нужна выборка? `var result = Persons.Where(x=>x.inf3 >= 24);`. Вы же как уже наверно догадались, полезли не в те дебри... Ну а вообще, нет доступа через LINQ это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, пару минут назад сам понял об этом, и не понимаю как не понял это сразу

Comment: @EvgeniyZ запостите как ответ?

Comment: @Kromster Нет, ибо как я однажды сказал - я против таких вопросов и всеми руками буду за их удаление/закрытие. От него нет пользы для сообщества, автор не хотел думать и сразу пошел строчить вопрос, да и по сути можно закрыть дубликатом на любой вопрос по десериализации JSON. Если хотите +к репутации, дерзайте, я не против.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но я не вижу от вас ни голоса за закрытие, ни минуса .. ? Если вы не против, размещу ваш ответ как "общий". Все же вопрос и ответ не так уж плохи

Comment: @Kromster Я капля в море, мой голос мало чего изменит, против я - не против другие. Я направил человека в правильное русло, дальше уже пусть сообщество SO смотрит что оно хочет, я же, посижу в стороне. Также на сколько я знаю, вопросы без ответов, голосов или с ответами без голосов рано или поздно удаляются - мне этого достаточно, я не буду человеку портить репутацию и впечатления минусами, бессмысленно. А дубликат - [типичная закрывашка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/220553), похоже на него? От части да, от части нет. Может вы и правы, стоит проголосовать за этот дубликат.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Если EvgeniyZ не против, перенесу его комментарии в ответ:*

---

Где вы тут увидели массив без названия? Я например вижу корневой объект, который является массивом объектов. Так может все же `.Deserealize<Person[]>` (массив можно заменить для удобства на `List<>`)?

Вы просто пишете не так, вы обращаетесь к `Persons`, естественно там не будет свойств нужных вам, ибо это коллекция. Что вам надо? Достать один объект? Пожалуйста - `var result = Persons.FirstOrDerault(x=>x.inf1 == 5);` Или нужна выборка? `var result = Persons.Where(x=>x.inf3 >= 24);`. Вы же как уже наверно догадались, полезли не в те дебри... Ну а вообще, нет доступа через LINQ это уже совсем другой вопрос.