# Как я могу получить нужные данные из json

Tags: c#, json

Есть JSON:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "total": 0,
  "metadata": {
    "next_page": "https://api.picsart.com/photos/search.json?popular=1&tag=origfte&animated_support=1&photo_history_inclusion=photo&q=origfte&offset=60"
  },
  "response": [
    {
      "license": "fte",
      "id": 335733859043201,
      "url": "https://cdn131.picsart.com/335733859043201.jpg",
      "title": "#sunset #sunsetloverparadise #idilicscenery #sunsettime #beautifulsunset #seaview #horizon #skyandclouds #sunsetsky #singletree #palmtree #birdsinflight #silhouettes #nature #summertime #warmweather #sunsetcolors #summersunset #naturephotography                                                                                             #freetoedit",
      "tags": [
        "sunset",
        "sunsetloverparadise",
        "idilicscenery",
        "sunsettime",
        "beautifulsunset",
        "freetoedit"
      ],
      "mature": false,
      "width": 1000,
      "height": 1229,
      "created": "2020-08-21T19:24:19.719Z",
      "type": "photo",
      "public": true,
      "likes_count": 4064,
      "comments_count": 25,
      "streams_count": 1003,
      "reposts_count": 117,
      "forks_count": 1001,
      "show_edit_history": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 183644448001102,
        "username": "macmmaya",
        "name": "M",
        "photo": "https://cdn140.picsart.com/316055570221201.jpg",
        "is_verified": true
      },
      "history_uploaded": false,
      "sources_count": 0,
      "has_similars": true
    },
    {
      "license": "fte",
      "id": 334378552034201,
      "url": "https://cdn141.picsart.com/334378552034201.jpg",
      "title": " #freetoedit  #myedit #papicks #heart #cloud #background #clonetool #moon",
      "tags": [
        "freetoedit",
        "myedit",
        "papicks",
        "heart",
        "cloud",
        "background",
        "clonetool",
        "moon"
      ],
      "mature": false,
      "width": 1189,
      "height": 1516,
      "created": "2020-08-06T02:55:52.331Z",
      "type": "photo",
      "public": true,
      "likes_count": 4074,
      "comments_count": 15,
      "streams_count": 1813,
      "reposts_count": 165,
      "forks_count": 9831,
      "show_edit_history": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 255256878013102,
        "username": "taylse",
        "name": "taylse",
        "photo": "https://cdn130.picsart.com/333269874039201.jpg",
        "is_verified": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Как мне получить `url` и отобразить их в `ListBox`?

Мои попытки:

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "JsonData.json");
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
{
    var json = file.ReadToEnd();
    Dictionary<string, object> result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
    string pictures = result["response"].ToString();
    List<Rootobject> objResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(pictures);
    PicsList.ItemsSource = objResponse;
}
```

Comment: Если разговор идет про JSON, то наверно стоит предоставить его? Также отформатируйте код, убрав лишнее, ибо такое читать весьма трудно.

Comment: ок спасибо!!! 

Comment: За что? Вы не сделали нечего, что я просил, где JSON?

Comment: Так то лучше @EvgeniyZ ??

Comment: Да, теперь я убедился в том, что это дубликат. Только не понятно, в чем у вас проблемы? Он ведь простой, нету чего либо "замудренного".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить объект такого вида на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: это понятно как получить класс быстро и удобно но мне нужно конкретно с этого класса получить все url и показать это все на uwp вот этот часть не получаеться

Comment: Ну вам изначально надо его распарсить, а уж затем брать то, что вы хотите. Как это сделать - ссышка выше, генерируете классы (можете удалить лишнее поля) и десериализировать в них. Можете через `JObject`, будет тогда нечто такое: `foreach (var item in json["response"]){ id = (long)item["id"]; }`, но крайне не советую данный вариант!

Comment: ок тепер все понятно спасибо,осталось создать галерия или все картинки добавить в grid 
<Image Source="https://cdn141.picsart.com/334378552034201.jpg" Name="myimage" />

так только одну картинку могу отобразить но какой самый удобний вариант для всех картинок?

Comment: Почитайте про привязки и используйте `ItemsControl`, либо то, что на нем базируется (`ListBox`). Там все очень просто, всего пару строк кода, а именно `DataContext = нужныйКлассСДанными` (задаем окну источник данных, где лежат свойства для привязки), `public List<string> Images {get;}` (публичное свойство для привязки) и `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"/>` (привязываем свойство к контролу). За основу брал WPF, в UWP могут чуть отличаться названия, но суть такая же. Вот научитесь этому и жизнь станет в разы легче.