# C# Конвертация json в List<string>

Tags: c#, json, list

Имеется ответ от сервера:

```
{
  "UserInfo": [
    {
      "A": "818604003",
      "B": "15522690003",
      "C": "Y",
      "D": "0",
      "E": {},
    }
  ]
}
```

Будет написано большое кол-во автотестов по методу, который возвращает данный json выше, я хочу сделать автоматическую конвертацию в **List< string >** (мне нужно провалидировать поля, которые мне вернулись от сервера в соответствии с ожидаемым результатом, дабы не писать огромное кол-во полей в классы для десериализации, потому что ответы будут приходить по 50 - 100+ строк).
Идея была в том, чтобы разбить этот ответ Split'том и попробовать вытянуть нужные данные маппинга, по факту мне нужно сделать массив стринг НЕ пустых полей и далее просто сравнить с ожиданием, подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такой ситуацией и как выходили из нее.

Comment: 1) девериализовать в модель, которая соответствует вашему json 2) извлечь нужные вам данные для построения вашего списка.

Comment: под модель, что подразумеваете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/179763

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно что надо понять чтобы было понятным как строки списка из объектов json.....