# Ошибка десериализации Json Файла

Tags: c#, json

Есть много архивов состоящий из 1,5к+ Json файлов. при попытки десериализовать один из них у меня выходит либо пустой объект либо ошибка дисиарилизации пробовал 1000 вариантов.

ВОТ ТАК ВЫГЛЯДИТ JSON:

```
{
  "detection_result": {
    "CAM1": {
      "ships": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Object": {
            "ShipDetectionResult": {
              "position": {
                "xtl": 0.14427084,
                "ytl": 0.71481484,
                "w": 0.1,
                "h": 0.106481485
              },
              "object_confidence": 0.9816354,
              "class_confidence": 0.9815236,
              "ship_type": "Military"
            },
            "ShipPosition": {
              "sector": {
                "start": 306.34375,
                "end": 300.34375
              },
              "distance": 15315.777
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "CAM2": {
      "ships": []
    },
    "CAM3": {
      "ships": [
        {
          "Id": 0,
          "Object": {
            "ShipDetectionResult": {
              "position": {
                "xtl": 0.026041666,
                "ytl": 0.51574075,
                "w": 0.119791664,
                "h": 0.083333336
              },
              "object_confidence": 0.92843384,
              "class_confidence": 0.8889944,
              "ship_type": "Military"
            },
            "ShipPosition": {
              "sector": {
                "start": 223.4375,
                "end": 216.25
              },
              "distance": 17691.3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

сам код:

```
 private async void DeserializeFunction()
        {
            List<ListCamm> list = new List<ListCamm>();
            foreach (var link in _source2.Values)
            {                
                using (var file = ZipFile.OpenRead(link))
                {
                    foreach (var x in file.Entries.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains(".jpg") != true))
                    {
                        if (x.Name == String.Empty) continue;
                        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(x.Open());
                        var text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();                        
                        var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ListCamm>>(text);

                        item.ForEach(x => list.Add(x));
                    }                    
                }                
            }
        }
```

Comment: `List<ListCamm>` это `[{},{},{}...]`, а у вас json `{"detection_result":{}}`, вообще даже не близко.

Comment: получается большая модель классов, должен быть просто вариант распарсить json в нужный тебе вид модели

Comment: Так оптимизируйте, уберите лишнее. Убирание лишнего не влияет на процесс десериализации.

Comment: Влияет, он просто не десерилизуется при данном виде Json Файла

Comment: `detection_result` больше похож на `Dictionary<string, Cam>`, думайте в эту сторону.

Comment: мне нужны внутренние объекты а не внешние, нельзя просто взять и пропустить внешние объекты при десирилизации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж вам [способы генерации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/373567) модели не помогли, давайте разберем модель ручками

Для начала легеда:

- `[]` - массив
- `{}` - объект
- `"свойство": <значение>` задает пару из ключа - имени свойства и его значения какого-то типа

Про строки, числа и null писать не буду, это, как мне кажется в рамках текущего вопроса выглядит просто.

Начну из глубины, вот этот фрагмент.

```json
"position": {
  "xtl": 0.14427084,
  "ytl": 0.71481484,
  "w": 0.1,
  "h": 0.106481485
},
```

Сейчас меня волнует то, что справа от `:` а именно некая структура в фигурных скобках. Очевидно, это объект, значит я должен создать класс и поместить в него 4 свойства, судя по десятичным дробным числам - типа `double`.

*Свойства в C# пишутся с большой буквы с использование политики именования `CamelCase`, то есть все слова в одно слово, каждое с большой буквы.*

```cs
public class Position
{
    public double Xtl { get; set; }
    public double Ytl { get; set; }
    public double W { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
}
```

`position` входит в состав некого объекта, в котором еще 2 свойства типа `double` и одно типа `string`.

```json
"ShipDetectionResult": {
  "position": <Position>,
  "object_confidence": 0.9816354,
  "class_confidence": 0.9815236,
  "ship_type": "Military"
},
```

Но вот незадача, автор этого JSON намешал политик именования, и почему-то воткнул сюда `snake_case`. Этот JSON вообще не выглядит качественным. Ну что поделать, воткну 3 костыля, смаплю свои свойства в правильном именовании к тем что в JSON используя атрибут `[JsonPropertyName]`.

```
public class ShipDetectionResult
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("object_confidence")]
    public double ObjectConfidence { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("class_confidence")]
    public double ClassConfidence { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("ship_type")]
    public string ShipType { get; set; }
}
```

Готово, теперь вот эта часть

```json
"ShipPosition": {
  "sector": {
    "start": 306.34375,
    "end": 300.34375
  },
  "distance": 15315.777
}
```

По полной аналогии с тем что выше

```
public class Sector
{
    public double Start { get; set; }
    public double End { get; set; }
}

public class ShipPosition
{
    public Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
}
```

`ShipPosition` и `ShipDetectionResult` живут в каком-то свойстве `Object`, слово `Object` зарезирвировано в C# базовым классом, поэтому назову его `ShipObject`. Вообще все равно как вы называете классы. Важно только как вы называете свойства внутри них.

```
public class ShipObject
{
    public ShipDetectionResult ShipDetectionResult { get; set; }
    public ShipPosition ShipPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Поднимаемся вверх, а там объект внутри массива `[{},{}...]`. Но нужно еще описать сам объект, вот этот

```json
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Object": {
    "ShipDetectionResult": <ShipDetectionResult>,
    "ShipPosition": <ShipPosition>
  }
}
```

Ничего нового, назову его `Ship`, потому что он живет в массиве `ships`.

```
public class Ship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ShipObject Object { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь сам массив, который живет в свойстве `Ships`, а оно в свою очередь в свойстве `CAM*`.

```
public class Cam
{
    public Ship[] Ships { get; set; }
}
```

Здесь я предположу, что название этого свойства я не знаю на этапе разработки текущей модели данных. Оно будет ясно при десереализации, а объект структуры.

Ведь я мог написать так

```
public class DetectionResult
{
    public Cam Cam1 { get; set; }
    public Cam Cam2 { get; set; }
    public Cam Cam3 { get; set; }
}
```

А если там будет еще `CAM4` или `CAM24`, придется переписывать код, а я не хочу.

Поэтому я не буду писать класс `DetectionResult`, и вместо этого сделаю через словарь, вот так

```
public class Detection
{
    [JsonPropertyName("detection_result")]
    public Dictionary<string, Cam> DetectionResult { get; set; }
}
```

Готово.

Десереализую

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }; // игнорировать регистр в названиях свойств при десереализации
Detection result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Detection>(json, options);
```

---

Модель данных в сборе

```
public class Position
{
    public double Xtl { get; set; }
    public double Ytl { get; set; }
    public double W { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
}

public class ShipDetectionResult
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("object_confidence")]
    public double ObjectConfidence { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("class_confidence")]
    public double ClassConfidence { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("ship_type")]
    public string ShipType { get; set; }
}

public class Sector
{
    public double Start { get; set; }
    public double End { get; set; }
}

public class ShipPosition
{
    public Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
}

public class ShipObject
{
    public ShipDetectionResult ShipDetectionResult { get; set; }
    public ShipPosition ShipPosition { get; set; }
}

public class Ship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ShipObject Object { get; set; }
}

public class Cam
{
    public Ship[] Ships { get; set; }
}

public class Detection
{
    [JsonPropertyName("detection_result")]
    public Dictionary<string, Cam> DetectionResult { get; set; }
}
```

Полностью ручная работа.