# Добавить поток в список и работать с ним

Tags: c#

```
    public int qwe(string Request)
    {
        captchaID++;
        if (ListThread.Count < 5)
        {
            string website = Func.Pars(Request, "websiteURL\":\"", "\"", 0);
            string key = Func.Pars(Request, "websiteKey\":\"", "\"", 0);
            var thread = new Thread(() => Worker(website, key, captchaID));
            ListThread.Add(thread);
            thread.Start();
        }

        return captchaID;
    }
```

Сейчас в список добавляется только 1 поток при вызове функции, как сделать что бы каждый вызов функции добавлялся новый поток?

Comment: `каждый вызов функции добавлялся новый поток?` Каждый вызов функции у вас стартует новый поток, который запускает `Worker`. То что вы хотите, у вас уже есть. Уточните вопрос. И как-то странно вы парсите JSON, есть же `System.Text.Json`, который [спарсит вам все в одну строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1380057/373567) и быстро. Еще неясно, зачем вы каждый раз создаете форму и нигде ее не используете.

Comment: По поводу запуска кучи задач с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняющихся, [вот есть примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567), выбирайте любой.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры, кривой код тоже поправил)