# Перебрать все значения вложенного JObject

Tags: c#, json

Есть строка JSON следующего вида:

```
{
"ДатаНачалаРасчета": "2022-02-18T00:00:00",
"ДатаОкончанияРасчета": "2022-03-18T23:59:59",
"ДанныеСотрудников": [
{
"ФИО": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
"Фамилия": "Иванов",
"Имя": "Иван",
"Отчество": "Иванович",
"ДатаУвольнения": "2022-02-18T00:00:00"
},
...
]
}
```

Из нее мне необходимо вытянуть все вложенные инстанции "ДанныеСотрудников" (т.е. всех людей, перечисленных в поле "ДанныеСотрудников"), чтобы в дальнейшем преобразовать в объект C# и отправить в БД.
Я могу получить отдельный вложенный параметр (например, ФИО), зная позицию элемента в массиве JSON, следующим образом:

```
UvolSotrJson.SelectToken("ДанныеСотрудников[0].ФИО").ToString()
```

Это вернет ФИО первого человека из списка "ДанныеСотрудников", т.е. Иванова.
Мне же необходимо посчитать количество вложенных записей "ДанныеСотрудников", чтобы пройтись по ним циклом и каждую запись по человеку сконвертировать в C#-объект. Каким способом возможно это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/220553

Comment: Вы можете обратиться к этому свойству как к JArray и пройтись по нему циклом.